# Update view of express real time using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, handlebars.js

I use handlebar as the view engine of my express app. But how to append the new coming data from socket.io??

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  io.on('connection', function(client) { 
            client.on('order', function(data) {
                console.log(data); //real time data from mobile app
                //what to do here?
            });
        });

    Orders.getOrdersByUserId(req.user.id, function(err,data){
      res.render('orders/index',{orders:data});
    })
});
```

Comment: so it appears that the index handlebars file is rendered to the client and then, asynchronously, socket.io can send new information on to client (in your case, a new order comes in). This new information will have to be added by JavaScript to the DOM. That initial view rendering with handlebars already happened.

Comment: @MatthewVita I know, but how? should I put the io on the cilent instead of my express's route?

Comment: I can put together some sample code for you to accomplish this.

Comment: almost... done, just adding some notes and will post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the index handlebars file is rendered to the client and then, asynchronously, socket.io can send new information on to client (in your case, a new order comes in). This new information will have to be added by JavaScript to the DOM. That initial view rendering with handlebars already happened.

Here's a trivial example of how this would work...

./server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
  defaultLayout: 'main'
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('test', {testItems: [1,2,3]});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});
```

./views/layouts/main.handlebars

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

./views/test.handlebars

```
<ul class="test-items">
  {{#each testItems}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

<!-- TODO: obviously bring in jQuery the correct way -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: put custom javascript in individual files instead of inline. Also wire up Socket.IO on the server and the client... just using a mocked out message handler for a simple explanation -->
<script>
  // Mock socket message handler... this would be socket.io on the client side subscribing to a socket.io topic on the server
  setTimeout(function() {
    var inboundDummyData = 9001;
    $('.test-items').append('<li>' + inboundDummyData +'</li>');
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

RESULT: a list of 1, 2, 3 will show upon page load. 3 seconds later our mocked out Socket.io message handler will receive a message and add 9001 to that list.

Hopefully this gets you started. <strike>I will update my answer if I find out that Express Handlebars supports live updates of data, but it appears that it's only going to do the initial view rendering and that's it.</strike>

UPDATE: Did a bit of research... Express handlebars is great for that initial view, but doesn't support bindings afterwards. If you want server-based data-binding/"live updating", you should look into "Isomorphic JavaScript" (good article here: https://blog.risingstack.com/from-angularjs-to-react-the-isomorphic-way/) there are a few mature frameworks/libraries in this area at the moment. You can, of course, achieve the data-binding with just the frontend using a framework like Angular.js, React.js, or Knockout.js as well. Both techniques will work with Socket.IO and you should be able to find support for Handlebars with a bit of research.

Comment: this doesn't answer how to solve my above problem. I already use handlebar and it work, now I'm stuck at updating my view, where should I put my `data` which come from socket?

Comment: Socket.io on the client will subscribe to a Socket.io topic on the server. When the server broadcasts to your client, you'll have a handler that is invoked (I am demostrating that with my mock socket message handler timeout). This is the point where you will update the view. My answer touches on the fact that you can't simply update the handlebars view because that has already been rendered -- you'll have to update the DOM. Study up on https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client. How you get that data on the view is up to you (jQuery, Angular, React, etc).